# How to remove redis server from cloud66 stack?

Tags: redis, cloud66

How to remove redis server from cloud66 stack?
I installed redis server on cloud66 stack, but now I want to remove it, how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you have added that as Redis addon then you can simply remove the addon. If the addition was done through a redis gem client, then you can deploy the stack again without the gem or choose an external Redis server as an option.